# TFS 2010 Automated testing doesn't work

Tags: .net, tfs, mstest

I am configuring TFS 2010 to run automated tests. I have already configured an automated build using TFS. In the settings is configured to run all tests that apply to this pattern: `**\*test*.dll`. Since I use the default settings to create a test project, the assembly name is `[NameSpace].[Project].Test.dll`, which should apply the pattern. However, no test is runned.

When I add the test metadata file (.vsmdi) that is created with the test project, the TFS Build service gives the following error message:

```
TF270015: 'MSTest.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong? How can I fix this? Thank you!

**Update**

In the meantime, I got a warning: `Could not find a part of the path 'D:\My Builds\Projects\1002\Binaries\'.` I am building to custom folders as specified in the projects itself. I think MSTest.exe might look at that location.

How can I change the path where MSTest.exe will look for?

**Update 2**

I've changed the BinariesDirectory to the path the assemblies build to, which solves the problem! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this could be an environment issue. Did you install VS 2010 on your build box?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually, the TFS database itself is on another (file) server.

Comment: After your post, I reviewed the configuration. I did not understand the message (no controllers found) I get when I configured a test. But it seems that I need to install a test controller. I'll keep you posted

Comment: That's cool. I was wondering that you might need to manually run MSTest.exe to figure out further details.

Comment: By the way, I did found this out mostly because of running the MSTest.exe manually! Thank you @tonyjy!